# WEBSOCKETS: client does not revice the messages I send from server

Tags: java, javascript, websocket, byte, unsigned

I will try to explain my problem without attaching any code, I think that that is not needed.
Okay, I have a websocket client in JS that connects to my java server. The handshake is done, connected handler is called on the client, so I send a message to server, wich is readed. Then the message is reversed and sended back to the client, but the client messagerecived handler or any other handler are not called.

This is the message that I send to the client:

```
b[0]=-127;//Its the same of 129?
b[1]=1;
b[2]=18;//any char..
```

I think that the problem must be on the first byte. I write "b[0] = (byte)129;" but when I read it it returns -127, maybe because, ¿the byte 129 have to be unsigned?
Thanks for help :P

---

The requested client code:

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8">

<title>WebSocket Test</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var wsUri = "ws://localhost:10637/penise";
  var output;

  function init()
  {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    testWebSocket();
  }

  function testWebSocket()
  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }

  function onOpen(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    var msg = String.fromCharCode(1)+ String.fromCharCode(0)+"This is niceeee"
    doSend(msg);
  }

  function onClose(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
  }

  function onMessage(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
    websocket.close();
  }

  function onError(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  }

  function doSend(message)
  {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message); 
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeToScreen(message)
  {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);


function char(i) {
       return String.fromCharCode(i);
     }
</script>

</head><body><h2>WebSocket Test</h2>

<div id="output"><p style="word-wrap: break-word;">CONNECTED</p><p style="word-wrap: break-word;">SENT: This is niceeee</p><p style="word-wrap: break-word;"><span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> undefined</p><p style="word-wrap: break-word;">DISCONNECTED</p></div>

 </body></html>
```

Comment: The code of the client has been attached

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a buffer of unsigned bytes to avoid confusion.

Your main problem is that the first byte indicates that the payload is UTF-8 text, but the single byte value in your payload is 180 which is not a valid UTF-8 character. If you are trying to send a binary value then you need to indicate that in the first byte by setting the opcode to 0x2 rather than 0x1 (e.g. 130 rather than 129).

Comment: I made a mistake writing 180, I meant for example 18, or any char. Anyway, I have also tried to send the opcode 2, but the client does not call any handler.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have solved the problem. The problem was that, when i sent the header, I putted 2 "\r\n", instead of only one, so one of the \r\n becomes part of the next frame and the connection is broken (because it becomes the opcode of the next frame).

Thanks you for trying to help me <3